# Image stabilization on a list of 2D arrays representing grayscale images using OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, jitter

I'm trying to implement some jitter/movement correction on data (greyscale intensity images stored in hdf5 format) using the OpenCV package. Normally, I read in the data as a list of 2D arrays (using imshow to perform colourplots).

The standard way of reading in frames from a video file using `cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')` doesn't seem to accept my list of 2D numpy arrays which look something like:

```
[[243.25 228.5  238.75 ... 277.75 302.5  292.25]
 [255.   256.5  234.75 ... 295.25 289.25 272.5 ]
 [252.5  238.5  231.5  ... 294.25 279.75 285.  ]
 ...
 [253.   248.75 245.25 ... 334.5  282.   335.  ]
 [268.75 253.25 280.75 ... 329.75 338.5  329.25]
 [261.   252.75 254.75 ... 314.25 338.25 315.75]]
```

Is there any way to do this without having to save the files as images and then a video and then reading them back in via cv2?

I would like to use the goodFeaturesToTrack(), calcOpticalFlowPyrLK() and estimateRigidTransform() functions from cv2 to make sure that I am comparing the same points in space for each frame in the series.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a cv Mat and set data for it:

```
img = numpy.zeros([5,5,3])
img[:,:,0] = numpy.ones([5,5])*64/255.0
img[:,:,1] = numpy.ones([5,5])*128/255.0
img[:,:,2] = numpy.ones([5,5])*192/255.0

cv2.imwrite('color_img.jpg', img)
cv2.imshow("image", img)
cv2.waitKey()
```